# USB errors on startup

Tags: usb, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 22.04. When I restart my PC, I suddenly get these USB errors:

```
[    4.309940] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   14.782048] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   14.909933] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   25.534075] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   25.534359] usb usb1-port8: attempt power cycle
[   25.613938] usb 1-7.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   25.716235] usb 1-7.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0084, bcdDevice= 2.00
[   25.716246] usb 1-7.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   25.716251] usb 1-7.2: Product: Razer DeathAdder V2
[   25.716255] usb 1-7.2: Manufacturer: Razer
[   26.049930] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   31.166088] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   36.542080] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   36.777927] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   41.918068] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   47.294073] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   47.402106] usb usb1-port8: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I don't know what these errors mean. Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks.